# Custom Tabbar application ipad hide tabbar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

Hi I am developing an iPad application. I used to custom tab bar. Also tabbar buttons on left side of screen. I want to see full screen. So I tried this code for hide tabbar, but did not hide. I see gray space in screen bottom. Gary space height is IOS 7 about  49 px but IOS 6 about 20 px. What can I do.

```
- (void)hideTabBar
{
    for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            view.hidden = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Gray space in IOS 7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
 for(UIView *view in self.tabBarController.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 1024, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 1024)];
        }

    }
```

Note: this is tested in ios 6 and earlier versions, so if you want to run in ios 7 and more set frame and some flag for frame.

Comment: Thank you @Viruss mca. This code work IOS 6 and earlier version. But dont work IOS 7, like you said.I added screen shot. Can you help me

Comment: previous reply is working. But consists of 20 px black space at the bottom in ios 5.0. This black space is lost if I turned the screen. Do not have any problem with ios 6

Answer (score 0):

In the custom UITabBar view controller in viewDidLoad

```
  [self.tabBar setHidden:YES];
  [self.view addSubview:self.viewButton]; // you custom buttons array view
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple's implementation is more elegant as it stretches the `UITabBarController` view size enough to get its `tabBar` outside the screen, and at the same time it will automatically stretch the views of the contained view controllers.

If you just hide your tab bar, either there is no content "under it" (your gray space) or it won't recognize taps.

You should better subclass `UITabBar` and draw it a you like but still let `UITabBarController` show and hide it properly for you.

**Edit:**

Just realized that hiding the tab bar is not in the default SDK but in a [category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456166/ios-7-hide-tabbar-issue/22626639#22626639) I made long time ago.

Anyway stretching `UITabBarController`'s view frame seems to me the most elegant way to "hide" the tab bar (actually move it away from the screen) as you don't have to deal with subviews or hunt down the tab bar frame directly.

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456166/ios-7-hide-tabbar-issue/22626639#22626639) question.